# How do I convert HTML template with CSS properties into spreadsheet (.xlsx) file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, excel

I am trying to convert `HTML` template with `CSS` properties for invoice into spreadsheet `(.xlsx)` file. The template contains logo of the organization, customer details and tables. I want to convert the template as it is. I've tried some libraries but they were not helpful.

This is the code I've tried

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

// Create a new workbook
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

// Read the HTML template file
const html = fs.readFileSync('invoice.html', 'utf-8');

// Create a worksheet
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Invoice');

// Set up styles
const headerStyle = {
  fill: {
    type: 'pattern',
    pattern: 'solid',
    fgColor: { argb: 'D21312' },
  },
  font: {
    color: { argb: 'D21312' },
    bold: true,
  },
};

const cellStyle = {
  border: {
    top: { style: 'thin' },
    left: { style: 'thin' },
    bottom: { style: 'thin' },
    right: { style: 'thin' },
  },
};

// Create a JSDOM instance to manipulate the HTML
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(html);
const document = dom.window.document;

// Add the image to the worksheet
const imageFilePath = 'logo-dark.png';
const imageId = workbook.addImage({
  filename: imageFilePath,
  extension: 'png',
});
worksheet.addImage(imageId, {
  tl: { col: 1, row: 1 },
  ext: { width: 200, height: 200 },
});

// Extract the table data
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

// Iterate through rows and cells
rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
  const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
  cells.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
    const cellValue = cell.textContent.trim();

    // Set cell values and styles
    const excelCell = worksheet.getCell(rowIndex + 2, cellIndex + 1);
    excelCell.value = cellValue;
    excelCell.border = cellStyle.border;
    if (rowIndex === 0) {
      excelCell.fill = headerStyle.fill;
      excelCell.font = headerStyle.font;
    }
  });
});

// Save the workbook to a file
workbook.xlsx.writeFile('invoice.xlsx')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Invoice converted to Excel successfully!');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error converting invoice to Excel:', error);
  });
```

This is html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML Table Example</title>
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid rgb(243, 9, 9);
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
      }

      th {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }

      .logo {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .logo img {
        max-width: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="logo-dark.png" alt="Logo" /></td>
          <td>Data 1-2</td>
          <td>Data 1-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 2-1</td>
          <td>Data 2-2</td>
          <td>Data 2-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 3-1</td>
          <td>Data 3-2</td>
          <td>Data 3-3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```